# i want make a new json from the previous json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to make a new json from the previous json

can anyone help me ?

previous json

```
Array [
   Object {
    "idx": 1,
    "image_uri": "a",
    "webview_uri": "1",
 },
   Object {
    "idx": 2,
    "image_uri": "b",
    "webview_uri": "2",
 },
  Object {
   "idx": 3,
   "image_uri": "c",
   "webview_uri": "3",
 },
  Object {
   "idx": 4,
   "image_uri": "d",
   "webview_uri": "4",
 },
  Object {
   "idx": 5,
   "image_uri": "e",
   "webview_uri": "5",
 },
]
```

what i want to make json finally

what i want to make json

```
const new_Json =  [
           {
            source: {
                uri: 'a',
            },
        },
        {
            source: {
                uri: 'b',
           },
        },
        {
            source: {
                uri: 'c',
            },
        },
        {
            source: {
                uri: 'd',
            },

        },
        {
            source: {
                uri: 'e',
            },
        },
    ]
```

i think i can do with map loop but I do not think any way... is somebody help me ? it feel me stupid..

Comment: How will be the new json look like?

Comment: @brk i'm sorry i was editing

Comment: `previousJson.map(({ image_uri }) => ({  source: { uri: image_uri } }))`

Comment: @AswinKumar that source make `Object {
  "source": Object {
    "uri": "a",
  },
}
`

Comment: @doso what else you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `old_json` variable contains the previous data...

```
var new_json = [];
for(var i in old_json) {
  var row = old_json[i];
  new_json.push({"source": row.image_uri});
}
```